# 'be' that expresses position by linking the prepositional phase and the subject , or means 'exist in certain place'

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I am a boy.

I was tired.

I was in Las Vegas.

I know that the be verbs in the first two sentences are 'be's that link predicate adjectives or nouns. But I'm not sure about the last one. In some dictionaries, its 'meaning' is illustrated as 'exist in a certain place', and in some other dictionaries, its 'function' is illustrated as 'linking prepositional phrase or adverbials that shows time or location'. Which analysis is actually correct? How do the native speakers actually think of this 'be'?

Comment: The vast majority of native speakers don't think about grammar at all! It seems to me that  there are two shades of meaning here. The 'exist in a certain place' sense refers to permanent things - _There is a cathedral in Salisbury_. _I was in Las Vegas_ means that the speaker was visiting the place at a particular time, so your second definition applies here.

Comment: In your last example, "in Las Vegas" is a preposition phrase functioning as a locative **complement** of "be". We don't call it a predicative complement (your predicate adjs or nouns) like the AdjP and NP in your first two examples, but it is still a complement by virtue of being an obligatory element. Note that obligatory items are always complements -- they are required to complete the verb phrase.

Comment: So, when you said 'permanent things', did you mean that be verbs mean 'exist' when they are used in the simple present tense?

Comment: Permancy is irrelevant, and so is the term 'exist' The locative complement tells us where the subject (or object) is/was/will be at any moment in time, which is why it's called a locative complement.